# Plotting different rows as different lines in R with matplot

Tags: r, plot, rows, legend

I would like to plot different rows as different lines in the same plot to illustrate the movements of the average development of 3 groups: All, Men and Women. However, I'm not getting one of the lines printed and the legend is not being filled with the rownames.

I'l be glad for a solution, either in `matplot` or in `ggplot`.

Thank you!

[image]

Code:

```
matplot(t(Market_Work), type = 'l', xaxt = 'n', xlab = "Time Period", ylab = "Average", main ="Market Work")

legend("right", legend = seq_len(nrow(Market_Work)), fill=seq_len(nrow(Market_Work)))

axis(1, at = 1:6, colnames(Market_Work))
```

Data:

```
       2003-2005   2006-2008   2009-2010   2011-2013   2014-2016   2017-2018
All     31.48489    32.53664    30.41938    30.53870    31.15550    31.77960
Men     37.38654    38.16698    35.10247    35.65543    36.54855    36.72496
Women   31.48489    32.53664    30.41938    30.53870    31.15550    31.77960


> dput(Market_Work)
structure(list(`2003-2005` = c(31.4848853173555, 37.3865421137, 
31.4848853173555), `2006-2008` = c(32.5366433161048, 38.1669798351148, 
32.5366433161048), `2009-2010` = c(30.4193794808191, 35.1024661973137, 
30.4193794808191), `2011-2013` = c(30.5387012166381, 35.6554329405739, 
30.5387012166381), `2014-2016` = c(31.1555032381292, 36.5485451138792, 
31.1555032381292), `2017-2018` = c(31.7795953402235, 36.7249638612854, 
31.7795953402235)), row.names = c("All", "Men", "Women"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: you are only seeing two lines as women and all are the same value in your data

Comment: @user20650 jesus... what about the names in the legends? Is it possible to draw a grid on the background?

Comment: you could run `grid()` after then matplot call. To get the names use `legend("right", legend=rownames(Market_Work), ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with ggplot2. I changed some of your data, as two rows were same in your originial data.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(`2003-2005` = c(31.4848853173555, 37.3865421137, 
30.4848853173555), `2006-2008` = c(32.5366433161048, 38.1669798351148, 
30.5366433161048), `2009-2010` = c(30.4193794808191, 35.1024661973137, 
33.4193794808191), `2011-2013` = c(30.5387012166381, 35.6554329405739, 
33.5387012166381), `2014-2016` = c(31.1555032381292, 36.5485451138792, 
30.1555032381292), `2017-2018` = c(31.7795953402235, 36.7249638612854, 
30.7795953402235)), row.names = c("All", "Men", "Women"), class = "data.frame")
df2 <- as.data.frame(t(df))
df2$Year <- rownames(df2)
df2%>% pivot_longer( c(All,Men,Women), names_to = "Category") %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value)) + geom_line(aes(group = Category, color = Category))
```

[image]

Comment: Ty @Seshadri. The only think now is, when I'm trying to adapt the labels, "Category", "value", "year"... the code doesn't work anymore. How to I change that stuff, add up a title and so on? Ty again.

Comment: You can use the "+labs(y = "better y title", x = "better x title", title = "plot title")" to change the labels.

Comment: Hi @Seshadri. Thank you a lot. Is there also a way to put a vertical line over the 2009-2010 and write something on it, such as "event takes place"?

Comment: Please check out + geom_vline(xintercept = ...). Also geom_text for adding a text right next to it. There should be plenty of examples online.